# Concatenate Two NSDate String values

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I just confused that is there any default functionality for concatenating two NSDate values like 11-jan-2012 and 15-jan-2012 as 11-15-jan-2012.
also 11-jan-2012 and 15-jul-2012 as 11-jan-15-jul-2012.
Thx in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy you can.. You can get day and month and year

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger dayM = [components day];    
NSInteger monthM = [components month];
NSInteger yearM = [components year];
```

from which you can make this for each these days just change `NSDate` date with your format 
then concat each days as you need

Comment: boss the values are coming from array and it should get aligned automatically for different inputs.

Comment: can you say sample scenario for first date make for loop for array for example for(int i = 0;i<[array count];i++){// then put the four lines of code above with change values of NSDate arrayobjectatindex[i] thenmake public NSString and append date to it for each date }

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use this code

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:@"11-jan-2012"];
NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:@"15-jan-2012"];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents;
dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit |NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit  
                                                 fromDate:date1];
int day1 = [dateComponents day];    
int month1 = [dateComponents month];
int year1 = [dateComponents year];

dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit |NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit  
                                                 fromDate:date2];
int day2 = [dateComponents day];    
int month2 = [dateComponents month];
int year2 = [dateComponents year];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - %d %d %d", day1, day2, month1, year1];
```

Comment: yes instead of [formatter dateFromString:@"11-jan-2012"]; do [formatter dateFromString:yourstring];

Comment: Boss it should get changed automatically for different inputs like 11 Jan 2012 - 15 Jan 2012 as 11-15 -Jan -2012.Also for 11 Jan 2012 - 11 July 2012 as 11-Jan - 11- July 2012.

Comment: Use condition for it,like 
`if (month1 == month2)
{
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - %d %d %d", day1, day2, month1, year1];
}
else
{
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - %d %d %d %d", day1, day2, month1,month2, year1];
}`