# Concatenate Two NSdate String values like as follows :

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenate Two NSDate String values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097260/concatenate-two-nsdate-string-values)

Just confused that is there any default functionality for concatenating two NSDate values like `11-jan-2012 and 15-jan-2012 as 11-15-jan-2012`. also `11-jan-2012 and 15-jul-2012` as `11-jan-15-jul-2012`.

> 11 Jan 2012 - 15 Jan 2012 as 11-15 Jan 2012. 11 Jan 2012 - 11 July
>   2012 as 11 Jan - 11 July 2012 and 11 Jan 2012  - 11 July 2014 as 11
>   Jan 2012 - 11 July 2014.

it should accord automatically

Comment: You post is very unreadable, also say that it is urgent will not make people post an answer sooner if you post is hard to understand. I suggest you use proper english and explain to problem a bit better. Also at any thing you have tried. Also don't ask the same question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097260/concatenate-two-nsdate-string-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\you have to check your requirement.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:@"11-jan-2012"];
NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:@"15-jan-2012"];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents;
dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit |NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit  
                                                 fromDate:date1];
int day1 = [dateComponents day];    
int month1 = [dateComponents month];
int year1 = [dateComponents year];

dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit |NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit  
                                                 fromDate:date2];
int day2 = [dateComponents day];    
int month2 = [dateComponents month];
int year2 = [dateComponents year];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - %d %d %d", day1, day2, month1, year1];
```

you have to check month and year as per your requirement.